# PHP Anchor Issues

Tags: php, html, anchor

I am currently having a problem with this line of code:

```
echo "<td>"<a href="userdetails.php?".$row[username].">View Details</a></td>";
```

Basically on page creation, I want the link to become formatted as `userdetails.php?USERNAME` but it keeps throwing errors at me due to what I assume is a syntax error.
Any help would be much appreciated, I am somewhat new to PHP.

**Added note**: The entire chunk of code is this (the other lines work):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row[username]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[emailaddress]."</td>";
    echo "<td>"<a href="userdetails.php?".$row[username].">View Details</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Your quoting isn't right - look at the highlighting in the question.

Comment: Yeah that is what I suspected, could you possibly tell me what it should be?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong for two reasons: wrong quoting and wrong array index reference.

So bad:

```
echo "<td>"<a href="userdetails.php?".$row[username].">View Details</a></td>";
```

Should be either

```
echo "<td><a href=\"userdetails.php?".$row['username']."\">View Details</a></td>";
```

or

```
echo '<td><a href="userdetails.php?'.$row['username'].'">View Details</a></td>";
```

Can also be even less messy that way:

```
printf('<td><a href="userdetails.php?%s">View Details</a></td>', $row['username']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic PHP syntax. If you open a string with a quote, using that quote again closes the string:

```
echo "<td>"<a href="userdetails.php?".$row[username].">View Details</a></td>";
     ^--open
          ^--close
           ^---huh?
```

You need to escape the internal quotes that are part of your output:

```
echo "<td>\"<a href="userdetails.php?".$row[username].">View Details</a></td>";
          ^---
```

Comment: That will produce another error and another unwanted behavior though.

Comment: your answer is wrong. you produce broken syntax and still got wrong quoting

Answer (score 0):

use

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row["username"].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row["emailaddress"].'</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="userdetails.php?'.$row["username"].'">View Details</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?= $row['username']; ?></td>
<td><?= $row['emailaddress']; ?></td>
<td><a href="userdetails.php?<?= $row['username']; ?>">View Details</a></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
```

Only open PHP tags when PHP is needed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['username'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['emailaddress'].'</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="userdetails.php?'.$row[username].'">View Details</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```